# How to reset a vote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a very simple, youtube-like, like/dislike buttons, and a green-red rating bar, all works fine except "clear votes" button, I don't know how to reset values to 0;

```
$(function(){

var n = 1;
var m=1;
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
$(".good").stop().animate({'width':'+=2px'});
$(this).css('background','#060');
$(".voteDown").css('background','-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #5e5e5e 0%, #353535 100%)');
$("#votersGood").text(n+++" likes");
//$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

});
$(".voteDown").click(function(){
$(".good").stop().animate({'width':'-=2px'});
$(this).css('background','#C00');
$(".voteUp").css('background','-moz-linear-gradient(top,  #5e5e5e 0%, #353535 100%)');
$("#votersBad").text(m+++" dislikes");
//$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
});
$("#clear").click(function(){
    $(".message").fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
});
});
```

How to reset "n" and "m" values to 0, so counting can start from 0 ?

Comment: Have you tried n=0 or m=0? What have your tried so far which hasn't worked?

Comment: Which one is the "clear votes" button exactly?

Comment: @Gearóid well, i tried few things, to add another var like var num=n*0; but even if its set votes to 0 when i press vote button again, it cointinues to count likes nothing happend,
if i try $("#votersGood").text(n=0+" likes"); then on next button press i get error (actually a get NaN likes/displike)

Comment: @mistick, that is because you're declaring a new variable called `num`. You just need to reset the existing variables.

Comment: i understand that, that was just an experiment with code, since im not a very good with jquery, im still learning. but how to reset variables?

Comment: @mistick, see my answer. Just set them back to 0. Do not put the `var` keyword before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the variables back to 0?

```
$("#clear").click(function(){
    $(".message").fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    n = 0;
    m = 0;
    $("#votersGood").text(n + " likes");
    $("#votersBad").text(m + " dislikes");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
i didnt know that this is possible, to "reset" variables within some function, now i learned something new. its so simple, now im ashamed that i even asked something that simple.

Comment: @misticx, No need to be ashamed. It might be helpful if you read up on variable scoping, as it is something you should get familiar with. Anyways, if this solved your problem, please don't forget to accept an answer.